# Member statistics in Drupal

Tags: drupal, count, statistics, view, counter

I want my `Drupal` site to display in a page some statistics about my members.

`Example:`

Male student population: 50

Female student population: 40

Number of students who passed the exam: 30 etc

Is this possible? I tried playing with the Views module, but it displays results not "counts" which is what I'm after.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

user Statistics Pro module..it may help

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, is it this one? http://drupal.org/project/statspro . But unfortunately it's not updated to be compatible with Drupal 7 :(